# Stacked-bar in sub-plot using df with more than two columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, stacked-chart

My `df` contains three columns of monthly data. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aS3kqr1fniqXTQ5fdZ-jysWs4YaCVBfg/view?usp=sharing) is the file.
I want to plot all three columns for each month on top each other in a subplot using a stacked-bar. 
This is one of many codes I have tried:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, bottom = df['Yf'])
```

It creates a single plot with bars hang strangely (see Figure below).
[image]

I want to put it in a subplot and all columns are stacked together. So, the highest points in each month are the sum of the three parameters in corresponding months. I also want to have the freedom to arrange which parameter should go to the bottom, middle, and top.
I want something like this.
[image]
Searched on the internet, no solution yet.

Comment: Works fine on my toy dataset. What's the output of your dataset and what's your expected output?

Comment: Major edit to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround gives what I need.

```
ax1.bar(df.index, df['Yf'],  alpha=0.7, color='green')
ax1.bar(df.index, df['Lc'],  bottom=df['Yf'], alpha=0.7, color='red')
ax1.bar(df.index, df['Ls'],  bottom=df['Yf']+df['Lc'], alpha=0.7, color='c')
```

[image]

Thought there was a single line `ax1.bar` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bottom=df['Yf']` as this tells `plt` to place the bars at the heights of `df['Yf']`. So just:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

You can choose the order `(bottom, middle, top)`, like this:

```
orders = ['Yf', 'Ls', 'Lc']
df[orders].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

will put `Yf` at the bottom, then `Ls`, and `Lc` on top. Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it should be put in a subplot. This works for a single column, but not for multiple columns. ```ax1.bar(df.index, df['Ls'], 0.35, alpha=0.9, color='b')```

Comment: Create an `ax` object and pass `ax=ax` to plot function.